# How to bookmark in Foobar2000

Tags: bookmarks, foobar2000

I've been using Foobar2000 to listen to audiobooks for some time now and. The only thing that I miss using in this program is a bookmarking feature. The plugin recommended for it is **foo uie bookmarks**, but it doesn't work for me, and I wonder if I can add any other component to foobar which would enable me to simply press a keyboard key to bookmark a position within an audiboook so it is remembered and I can as easily get back to that part of the audibook whenever I wish.

I'm using Column UI component instead of the Default interface and I'd like bookmarking enabled with it, so I can keep the nice foobar skin I have installed.

Comment: Please have a look at [foo_skip](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?s=&showtopic=30361&view=findpost&p=760652). The developer *case* added a simple bookmarking feature in [version 1.78](http://www.saunalahti.fi/~cse/foobar2000/?changes=foo_skip). Currently I cannot test this feature, so this will be only a comment

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer nixda! I've tried this plugin with the Default UI and I can confirm that it does the basic function of bookmarking: I can assign a keyboard shortcut and bookmark a position in the book I listen to and it is remembered. The problem is that it is very basic bookmarking, which means that I can't bookmark more than one position so its use is limited to remembering where I stopped last time I opened the book.

Comment: What I need is a bookmarking option which would allow me an easy access to various parts of the book I can get back to any time, during the playback, after closing the application or changing the book. Another problem is that it doesn't work with Columns UI, and I use a beautiful Metro skin which I'd like to keep.

Comment: It doesn't work with columnsUI? Are you sure? I'm using the skipping functionality for years in my foobar with columnsUI

Comment: I've checked again and you are right, bookmarking works in both UI but only for songs (except for FLAC format), it doesn't work with audiobooks, although they are in mp3 or WMA format, BOOKMARKS field is missing in the metadata window http://postimg.org/image/4w4dq5s0j/ I don't know what is the reason but I've found out that the workaround to this problem is to manually insert BOOKMARK field  http://postimg.org/image/4m5811267/ and copy it, then select all the files in the audiobook list, go to properties and choose Paste fields command in the drop down menu http://postimg.org/image/o9uyx22tn/

Comment: And now it works for audiobooks too. Before that I had to tick the boxes in the settings for the Skip plugin to enable automatic bookmarking as well as autoupdate of the bookmarks http://postimg.org/image/e1ulw8vjf/, so the last position is always the one which is remembered. Even this problem with bookmarking audiobooks is a bit of an inconvenience, it wouldn't be too much of a problem for me if I could only bookmark more than one position and so use the bookmarking effectively, not only to remember the last played position.

Comment: I've made it work! The **foo uie bookmarks** works as advertised after all, only it would be really nice if someone put out a short guide for people who are not much knowledgeable about this stuff such as me :) Inserting panels from the main foobar window with Metro skin won't work, adding panels is possible only through Columns UI options, in the window under the Layout tab, by adding Bookmarks panel in one of the Panel Stack Splitter and placing it in the desired position on the main window. Here is a snapshot, more helpful than a thousand words :) http://postimg.org/image/96r9h7mx1/

Comment: It may seem simple now but without help it takes hours of playing around with different options to get to this, foobar is a great program, but not at least user-friendly when it comes to changing settings. Thanks for the help nixda!

Answer (score 1):

Is it feasible to get right of entry to a bookmark inside the Header / Footer of a document thru VBA?

I've found it clean to add textual content to the beginning or stop, however I couldn't discern it out using a bookmark.
Documents are break up into what Word calls StoryRanges.

Processing storyranges other than the principle frame of the record in VBA may be a piece of a hit and pass over affair, however in case you recognise wherein your bookmarks are, something like this ought to work ..

```
[VBA]ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEvenPagesHeaderStory).Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Select[/VBA]
```

if you can't make it function, or this does not fit the bill, submit again with some extra info and I'll take a better look.

Answer (score -1):

Foobar may not be the best for making multiple bookmarks.

The foo_uie_bookmarks plugin is about 15yrs old. I think thats why it did not work.

For the current version of foobar please use the plugins from
https://www.foobar2000.org/components

If you want just a single bookmark per file, then you can use this plugin https://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_skip

For multiple bookmarks per file, a player like smplayer would be better. Ctr-A is the shortcut.

Comment: Smplayer does not persist bookmarks. Saved bookmarks will be gone when the app is closed and reopened.

Comment: smplayer does persistently save bookmarks. If yours is not saving, check in the preferences section.